# Are there online resources which shows tourism statistics of a country?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, statistics

From what little or not I understand of Tourism, tourism statistics would fall and rise more according to economic, political conditions of host and guest countries rather than anything else. I have been hunting for an online resource which tells tourism statistics of two or more countries and you, the tourist could compare their statistics to find which are busy and which are not.

The simplest example to show the arbitrariness would be of the 17 EU member states. I am sure each of the 17 states would have different tourism statistics depending upon what interesting activities were taking place, how welcoming they are/were of foreigners and more factors that I do not know of.

Does anybody know of existence of such a resource ?

Comment: I was actually giving the european stats bit as an example. I'm looking for world statistics with comparative formula.

Comment: But country wide statistics can be deceiving.  A country with a million visitors and 15 popular spots to visit will be far less crowded than country with a million visitors and 2 popular spots.

Comment: @Tom - actually it goes even more complex than that, to get a truer sense need visa applications filled and visa rejections which actually would give a bit more insight into how things work.

Comment: Yes it is complex, that is why I stuck with the KISS principal.  But your visa aspect applies only to a specific segment of travelers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Tourism_rankings gives all the details I need.